# How to calculate Saturday in between two dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Week ends on Saturday and new week starts on Sunday.

I would like to determine date which will be a Saturday and split dates in SQL Server. Example below:

- Start_date - 09/11/2018 - Friday
- End_date   - 12/11/2018 - Monday
- Total number of days = 4

I would like split the days and end results as

- Start_date - 09/11/2018 - Friday
- Date1      - 10/11/2018 - Saturday
- Total number of days = 2
- Date2    - 11/11/2018 - Sunday
- End_date - 12/11/2018 - Monday
- Total number of days = 2

Another example ( start_date and end_date if there are more number of Saturdays e.g. )

- start-date - 04/05/2017
- end_date   - 31/05/2017

Then results should be like below :-

```
Date1       Date2       no. of days.
------------------------------------
04/05/2017  06/05/2017  3
07/05/2017  13/05/2017  7
14/05/2017  20/05/2017  7
21/05/2017  27/05/2017  7
28/05/2017  31/05/2017  4
```

Please help.

Thanks & Regards,
VG

Comment: Use a [tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/)

Comment: are you wanting to calculate the number of days between two dates?  Then use datediff() function.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you are looking for something like this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2017-05-04'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2017-05-31'

DECLARE @OutputTABLE AS TABLE
(
    StartDate DATE NOT NULL,
    EndDate DATE NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @NumberOfWeeks INT = DATEDIFF(week, @StartDate, @EndDate)
DECLARE @Counter INT = 0
DECLARE @TempDate DATE = DATEADD(week, @Counter, @StartDate)

WHILE @NumberOfWeeks >= 0
BEGIN
    IF @NumberOfWeeks = 0 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @OutputTABLE VALUES (@TempDate, @EndDate);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @OutputTABLE VALUES (@TempDate, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week ,0 , @TempDate) + 1, -1)));
    END

    SET @TempDate = DATEADD(week, @Counter + 1, DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, @StartDate), 0)))

    SET @NumberOfWeeks = @NumberOfWeeks - 1
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END

SELECT StartDate,
       EndDate,
       DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, EndDate) + 1 AS NumberOfDays
FROM   @OutputTABLE
```

Comment: Dear Mohammad, Thanks for your solution ... it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. I couldn't figure out a way with a recursive CTE since you can't aggregate in the recursive part of a recursive CTE.

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '20170504',
        @MaxDate DATE = '20170531'

DECLARE @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime

--DATE TABLE... ONE ROW FOR EVERY DAY IN RANGE
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DateTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DateTable

SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
        Dates = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
INTO    #DateTable
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Results
CREATE TABLE #Results (Date1 DATETIME, Date2 DATETIME, NumOfDays INT)

--INSERT FIRST ROW IN CASE IT STARTS ON A DAY OTHER THAN SUNDAY
INSERT INTO #Results
SELECT
    MIN(Dates) as Date1
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Dates) = 7 THEN Dates END) as Date2
    ,DATEDIFF(DAY,MIN(Dates),MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Dates) = 7 THEN Dates END)) + 1 as NoOfDays
FROM #DateTable


SET @StartDate = (SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Dates) = 1 THEN Dates END) FROM #DateTable)
SET @EndDate = (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Dates) = 1 THEN Dates END) FROM #DateTable)

--INSERT ALL FULL WEEKS
WHILE @StartDate < @EndDate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Results
    SELECT
        MIN(Dates) as Date1
        ,MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Dates) = 7 THEN Dates END) as Date2
        ,DATEDIFF(DAY,MIN(Dates),MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Dates) = 7 THEN Dates END)) + 1 as NoOfDays
    FROM #DateTable
    WHERE Dates >= @StartDate

    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY,7,@StartDate)
END

--INSERT LAST ROW IF IT ISN'T A FULL WEEK
IF (SELECT MAX(Date2) FROM #Results) <> @MaxDate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Results
    SELECT
        MIN(Dates) as Date1
        ,MAX(Dates) as Date2
        ,DATEDIFF(DAY,MIN(Dates),MAX(Dates)) + 1 as NoOfDays
    FROM #DateTable
    WHERE Dates > (SELECT MAX(Date2) FROM #Results)
END


SELECT * FROM #Results

DROP TABLE #Results
DROP TABLE #DateTable
```

**RETURNS**

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+
|          Date1          |          Date2          | NumOfDays |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+
| 2017-05-04 00:00:00.000 | 2017-05-06 00:00:00.000 |         3 |
| 2017-05-07 00:00:00.000 | 2017-05-13 00:00:00.000 |         7 |
| 2017-05-14 00:00:00.000 | 2017-05-20 00:00:00.000 |         7 |
| 2017-05-21 00:00:00.000 | 2017-05-27 00:00:00.000 |         7 |
| 2017-05-28 00:00:00.000 | 2017-05-31 00:00:00.000 |         4 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score -1):

This will compute your Date2 from your Date1

```
print dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(wk,datepart(wk,'4/5/2017'),'1/1/2017'))
```

Comment: Dear All,Thanks for your prompt responses... much appreciated. I will try couple of solutions given in the post and update you over the weekend. warm regards VG